# How can I organize my video collection and update meta data?

Tags: video, freenas

I have a large collection of downloaded video files containing different movies, tv shows and music videos. I have a FreeNAS box set up that uses Fuppes as a UPnP media server. My media player on Windows correctly detects this UPnP collection and can stream from it fine.

However, All of my music videos, tv shows and movies are all sorted under the same 'Videos' group. I would like to seperate the different types of video files so that they can correctly go under 'Recorded TV' or whatever the case may be.

Any ideas?

I guess I am looking for something like an MP3Tagger but for video files?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173929/standard-meta-data-format-for-video-like-id3-tag-for-audio), there does not seems to be any standard format. As a consequence, contrary to your (or my) mp3 library, hosted on an UPnP server and usable through the house, it seems like it will take a lot more work to have a quality video library.

[This lifehacker guide](http://lifehacker.com/5505849/how-to-whip-your-movie-and-tv-show-art-into-shape-for-xbmc-and-boxee) expplains how [Media Companion](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/billy.adamson1/) can help you get all the informations you want. But there is not the slightest word on how these informations can be embedded for UPnP streaming.

Then, you have two solutions

1. Revert to SMB share, and put metadata in movie folder
2. use [FuPPes virtual folders](http://fuppes.ulrich-voelkel.de/wiki/index.php?title=Virtual_folder_configuration), if possible, to read metadata and organize files accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should try Serviio.  It will read metadata from the internet and present accordingly to your DLNA client.  I use it for my PS3.  It will also read XBMC .nfo files, so if you have a utility like Media Companion or any one of the other (XBMC/media) scrapers, you can automatically populate the .nfo files with the metadata, and Serviio will parse it and present through categories on your device (like Movies, Series, Titles, Genre, Actors, etc).

There's a way to install serviio on freenas (0.7) itself and have it running there.  You'd have to check serviio/freenas forums for further details on installation.  I haven't gotten that far with it.  I'm still putting my FreeNAS together.